# ES6 imports from CDK-constructed NodeJs 20.x AWS Lambda with inline code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

For e.g. quick and dirty listeners I've used lambdas on the Node.js 18.x. Now with Node.js 20.x I tried to ES6 imports etc but I can't get it to work since I've understood that I would have to

a) include a package.json with type=module and multiple files doesn't work with inline code
or
b) have the handler be index.mjs but it becomes index.js automatically

Have I understood the restrictions wrong or if I have not, is there some workaround that would allow for the quick, single-file inline-code-lambda to be marked as ES6?

I'm using the method `Code.fromInline` in CDK to create the lambda.

Comment: "have the handler be index.mjs but it becomes index.js automatically": what exactly does it mean?

Comment: When using the Java CDK, it appears that with Code.inline, the file name of the handles is automatically suffixed .js

Comment: Please add it to the post body, preferably with a piece of code which would reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some workaround that would allow for the quick, single-file inline-code-lambda to be marked as ES6?

This code works perfectly with Node.js 20.x, when saved to the single file `index.mjs` in the root folder, and the handler set to `index.handler`:

```
import { readdir } from 'node:fs/promises';

export const handler = async () => {
  const files = await readdir("/");
  console.log(files);
}
```

This lines up with what the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html) says:

> By default, Lambda treats files with the `.js` suffix as CommonJS modules. Optionally, you can designate your code as an ES module. You can do this in two ways: specifying the type as module in the function's `package.json` file, or by using the `.mjs` file name extension. In the first approach, your function code treats all `.js` files as ES modules, while in the second scenario, only the file you specify with `.mjs` is an ES module. You can mix ES modules and CommonJS modules by naming them `.mjs` and `.cjs` respectively, as `.mjs` files are always ES modules and `.cjs` files are always CommonJS modules.

---

As for creating the function from CDK, it seems you're hitting a platform limitation. CDK works by transforming your code into a CloudFormation stack, and in CloudFormation, there is no way to specify the name or the extension of the handler file, if you're using [inline code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html):

> ZipFile
>
> (Node.js and Python) The source code of your Lambda function. If you include your function source inline with this parameter, AWS CloudFormation places it in a file named `index` and zips it to create a deployment package. This zip file cannot exceed 4MB. For the Handler property, the first part of the handler identifier must be `index`. For example, `index.handler`.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/27980) on CDK about this.

Comment: The wall I'm hitting is probably with the Java CDK, when defining a lambda function using Code.fromInline, the code always ends up in a file with a .js suffix as far as I have seen